# Keep one layer always on top of the rest?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting, plugin

Is there a script/plugin that could make one layer appear always on top?

I am busy with a website design and I created some safe zones which I like to have on top at all times. However, now when I create a new layer I have to manually move that one layer up, which kinda slows downs my production time.

So is there any way of doing this with a script/plugin?

I added a screenshot of what my safe zones look like.

[image: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: You might as well select a layer below your top layer before pressing the 'new layer' button--that new layer will be below the top layer. Don't forget to lock the top layer to prevent accidentally selecting or moving it.

Comment: I always use shortcuts for practically everything, so that is'nt really an option because I have to adjust my workflow. Is'nt there anything else you can think of?

Comment: I don't see the problem. A new layer (cmd+shift+n) will be added on top of the current selected layer. If you work underneath the guide layer, a new one will not be added on top most.

Comment: So use opt+[ and opt+] (or alt+[ and alt+])to navigate layers when you need to. (Not knowing a shortcut doesn't mean it's not there.)

Comment: I know those shortcuts, but that does not answer my question. I just wanted to know if there was like a script/plugin/setting to keep it on top to ease things out. Ill just have to adjust my workflow then

Comment: Even I felt like having this kind of option. I think photoshop should include this option in their next release, If it make sense. :p

Answer (score 2):

Put a layer at the top, lock it, and then work in groups. This way when you create a new layer it will appear in the group of the element or page you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is add 3 big folders to my work. Header, Body and Footer cause for a web designer these are very easy to distinguish.

Place all my static layers in the Header, in the Footer I usually have stuff like copyright and lower menu and I always work in my Body, every other thing is there, therefore I do not need to open any other folder and doing so when i create a new layer it will always be made as a child of the Body, cause my focus will always be on that folder.

To make it even more distinguishable,  I always select folder colors. Always the same colors. After some time you will do this automatically and it will become a healthy habbit of your workflow.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Might be too late, but [here's a *Pinned Layers* plugin](https://adobe.com/go/cc_plugins_discover_plugin?pluginId=7682b070) in Adobe Marketplace for Ps v22

Comment: Hello and welcome, this post is rather useless if that link ever dies. At minimum at least name the plugin so that it can be searched in such a event. But better yet describe where the link is going and warn that its a direct launch...

Comment: It's an Adobe marketplace link to a plugin. It doesn't launch anything directly, unless you have Adobe CC installed and configured it specifically to handle marketplace links on your computer. Added a plugin title.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that.
But you just have to use guides, they are always on top of the design.
To manage the guides you can download [Guideguide](http://guideguide.me/)

Comment: I Have Guideguide and I use guides as well. This visual safe zone is easier to see when I have a dozen of guides. Guides are sometimes annoying when I have a lot of content.

Comment: We also use safe zones, and we just lock them on a high layer and work from a lower layer and it's usually pretty comfortable

Answer (score 0):

Holding cmd or ctrl when clicking a new layer, creates new layer below, rather than above