# Is there a way to lock a layer/group at the top of the layer stack in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Been looking around, can't find anything on this. I would like it so that if I lock a layer at the top of the layer stack no other layers can be placed above it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48887/keep-one-layer-always-on-top-of-the-rest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep one layer always on top of the rest?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48887/keep-one-layer-always-on-top-of-the-rest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. Unfortunately there isn't a way to 'lock' a layer to the top.

As suggested in [the answers to this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48887/keep-one-layer-always-on-top-of-the-rest), however, if you put the layer you wish to 'lock' at the top and then work inside a layer group (or folder), any new layers you create will automatically appear inside that group, meaning that your 'locked' layer will always stay at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if someone finds this post, [here's a plugin](https://adobe.com/go/cc_plugins_discover_plugin?pluginId=7682b070&workflow=share) for Ps v22 that might help